# Jquery+(Regex?) Replace text with img from string

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace text with the an img using part of itself:

```
<li class='custom'>
 <legend>images:</legend>
 {[img.png][1desc][2desc]} {[img2.png][1desc2][2desc2}
</li>
```

I want it to appear as this:

```
<li class='custom'>
 <legend>images:</legend>
 <img src="img.png" title="1desc - 2desc"/> <img src="img2.png" title="1desc2 - 2desc2"/>
</li>
```

Current code I am using(doesn't work):

```
<script>
function textToImg(theImg) {
  return theImg.replace(
           /\{\s*[\s*(.*?)\s*]\s*[\s*(.*?)\s*]\s*[\s*(.*?)\s*]\s*\}/gi,
           '<img src="$1" title="$2 - $3"/>'
         );
}

jQuery('li.custom').each(function() {

    current = jQuery(this);

    IMG = textToImg(current.html());

    current.html(IMG);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the text "string" in div#string manually editable? What I mean is: can you really garantee that the syntax given in the example will always be adhered to?

Comment: The string itself is fully editable so someone could mess up the syntax, though that's the least of my worries.

Comment: You really need to make an attempt at this yourself. Expecting a complete bbCode parser as a question when no attempt has been made is a bit too broad. If you have made attempts, please post that code

Comment: I've attempted using regex with .replace() but was unable to determine is the tag in the li.custom was present in div#string and apply the img. The code wouldn't have been much use as it didn't work at all

Comment: Updated question, slightly different now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done the jQuery bit, since I have been constructing my solution on my rather old iPod, but the RegExp part will do the trick.

First I put together a little utility function `rall(r,s)` which will apply the RegExp method `exec(s)` multiple times on the regular expression `r`. The function will return an array of arrays, each one of the structure `[whole match,capture1,capture2,capture3,...]`.

The regular expression string was put together from three subparts `t` (please note the double `\`: one of them is always eaten up at string generation time) and then turned into a regular expression by `new RegExp(string, flags)`.

Using the JavaScript Array methods `map()` and `join()` I eventually turned it into a string again which I stored back into the original string `s` (see console output).

```
var t,r,s='{[img.png][name1][desc1]} {[img2.png][name2][desc2]}';

function rall(r, s) { // utility: apply r.execs(s) multiple times
 var a=[],t,g=r.global;
 do {t=r.exec(s);if (!t) break;
     a.push(t);} while (g);
 return a;
}

t='\\s*\\[\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\]';
r=new RegExp('\\{'+t+t+t+'\\s*\\}','g');
s=rall(r,s).map(function(f){
 return '<img src="'+f[1]+'" title="'+f[2]+'">'+f[3];
}).join('<br>\n');
console.log(s);
```

Just noticed that I configured my output a little different from yours. I leave it up to you to put that right. ;-)

**Edit**

Having played around with my little utility function and getting it to work was one thing ...

But - using the regular expression from above (here: written out directly)

```
r=\{\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\s*\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\s*\}/g;
```

you can do the whole thing also with just one `String.replace()` call:

```
s.replace(r,'<img src="$1" title="$2 - $3">');
```

This will produce

```
<img src="img.png" title="name1 - desc1"> <img src="img2.png" title="name2 - desc2">
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly